# RPA | BluePrism | stack imbalance

Tags: blueprism

I encountered one exception during stepping, I clicked Ok and set next stage to a previously executed stage. In these kind of scenarios blueprism mostly give below error :

"Internal : stack imbalance has reached"

Why am I getting this error?

Please help.

Comment: The BP debugger doesn't support reverting control to a previous point in a running process. That's probably why you're getting the error.

Comment: Not sure of the exact underlying cause, but I find this happens way more frequently when stepping through a process, hitting an exception with a resulting "Recover," and not allowing the flow to hit a "Resume" at some point. If you "Set Next Stage" on a Resume and then to the desired portion of the process, it should prevent 90-95% of these from occurring.

Answer (score 6):

Stack imbalance errors can happen in Blue Prism if:

- You step over too fast in Debug Mode (step over before the current stage ends)
- The process or business object is in Exception mode and a new Exception is thrown(for instance if an Action stage throws an Exception after a Recover stage but before a Resume stage).

To recover from a Stack Imbalance error you can:

- Reset
- Or just run a Resume stage and continue debugging

Answer (score 2):

Stack imbalance is caused by moving too fast forward while in debug mode. I can't know exactly how it works but I suspect the behavior is as follows:

When you press F10(Jump over), you will execute the process and system will push a return adress to the stack. If you then press F10 again before exiting the first process you will push new things onto of the stack and now you have created an imballance on the stack and the return adress will be false when the first process tries to pop from the stack.

To know more about the stack in general see wiki link: [Wiki Call Stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)

Answer (score 1):

This error is thrown when you are in recover mode (an exception has already occurred but has not cleared by a resume stage) and manually set to run another stage and and another exception occur again.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that you didn't handle the exception properly by passing the exception through ***Resume*** and ***Recover***. If the an exception broke it must go through ***Recover*** and ***Resume*** to be resolved or else it will throw **Stack imbalance Error**

Answer (score 0):

I started working on BluePrism just few months back, and believe me I have got this error a lot of times. According to what I have noticed, this error occurs in debug mode. That is when you are running your code by "Stepping In".

If you have run a Stage, and stepped in while the current Stage is still running you'll get this error.

To get your code back running, you can try the below:

1. Reset the page
2. Reset the Process/Object entirely
3. If you are getting this error while running a page that is being called from another page. Then - Run the page in debug mode again from where it is being called. In this case you will not have to reset your Code.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you must hit the RESET buton.